# Code giving arror that cannot find length of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

Code is giving the error that:

> cannot read property length of undefined in    arr[i].length

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] === elem) {
        arr[i].splice(j, 1);
        
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([
  [3, 2, 3],
  [1, 6, 3],
  [3, 13, 26],
  [19, 3, 9]
], 3));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? 1) If you want splice an array while loping through it, you need to loop in the reverse order 2) `j` is the index for inner array.  Why are you using it for `arr.splice()`. 3) What is `newArr = [...arr]` supposed to do?

Comment: Why are you using `j` as an index into `arr` rather than `arr[i]` when you do `arr.splice(j, 1);`?

Comment: There's no need to assign `newArr` every time through the loop. Just do it once at the end.

Comment: `arr.splice(j, 1);` is modifying the array you are trying to loop over.  You removed an element, that's why it's saying `arr[i]` is undefined when you try to loop to the element you removed.

Comment: If an array has `elem` in it, you want it removed from `arr`?

Comment: Thanks found my mistake

Comment: you should probably use `.filter()`

Comment: @AdityaLamba if your issue is resolved, you can delete it.

Comment: Also look into `.includes()`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array while iterating over it, reducing it's length, causing you to access the array out of bounds, since the first `for` loop is looping until the the original value of `arr.length - 1`. I think you want to use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead to get the portion of array you want.